# Error: No resource type specified (at 'id' with value '@android:id=list')

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

What does the error mean?

```
package conde.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;
import android.app.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.database.sqlite.*;
import android.content.*;
import java.util.*;
import android.database.*;
import android.R.*;

public class MKBApplication extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Button aBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    Button dBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);
    private GroceryDataSource datasource;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        datasource = new GroceryDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();
        List<Grocery> values = datasource.getAllGroceryItems();
        ArrayAdapter<Grocery> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Grocery>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayAdapter<Grocery> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Grocery>) getListAdapter();
        Grocery grocery = null;
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.addBtn:
                String[] name = new String[] { "Pork", "Chicken", "Onion" };
                String[] quantity = new String[] { "1/2 kilo", "3 kilos", "1 kilo" };
                int nextInt = new Random().nextInt(3);
                grocery = datasource.createGroceryItem(name[nextInt], quantity[nextInt]);
                adapter.add(grocery);
            break;
            case R.id.deleteBtn:
                if (getListAdapter().getCount() > 0) {
                    grocery = (Grocery) getListAdapter().getItem(0);
                    datasource.deleteGroceryItem(grocery);
                    adapter.remove(grocery);
                }
            break;
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        datasource.open();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        datasource.close();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World, MKBApplication"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/addBtn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ADD"
/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/deleteBtn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DELETE"
/>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id=list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:id="@+id/list"`

Comment: Check your `listview` id. It should be android:id = "@+id/list1".

Comment: Please format your question better, are the `===`s and `...`s necessary?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id=list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

should be

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Comment: I have don that already .. and it still has errors ... It says


-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\user\Documents\CONDE_FRANCIS\Conde_App\bin\classes
    [javac] C:\Users\user\Documents\CONDE_FRANCIS\Conde_App\src\conde\app\MKBApplication.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             setListAdapter(adapter);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<Grocery>)
    [javac]   location: class MKBApplication
    [javac]